# Testing stochasticity of Business Investor model in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am working on the Business Investor model on netlogo. The question asks to use the attached frequencies ([Frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D52RQ.png)) as probabilities of investors choosing each decision alternative to show how often turtles move to all combinations of higher versus lower investment return (only move once per tick). Is anyone aware of how to do this?
Thanks.

```
globals
   [ years-simulated
     num-investors
     patch-mean-profit
     patch-min-risk
     patch-max-risk
     decision-time-horizon
    ]

   patches-own
    [
      profit
      annual-risk
     ]

   turtles-own
    [
      wealth
      current-utility
     ]

 to setup

 clear-all
 reset-ticks

 set years-simulated    50
 set num-investors 25

 set patch-mean-profit    5000
 set patch-min-risk  0.01
 set patch-max-risk  0.1

 set decision-time-horizon 5

 ask patches
  [
    set profit random-exponential patch-mean-profit
    set annual-risk patch-min-risk + random-float 
   (patch-max-risk - patch-min-risk)
   set pcolor scale-color green profit 0 (3 * patch-mean-profit)
   set plabel precision annual-risk 2
    ]

   crt num-investors
   [
     move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]
     set wealth 0.0
     pen-down
    ]
   end

   to go
    tick
    if ticks > years-simulated [stop]
    ask turtles [reposition]
    ask turtles [do-accounting]
    end

  to reposition
   let potential-destinations patches in-radius sensing-radius with [not any? turtles-here]
   set potential-destinations (patch-set potential-destinations patch-here)
   let best-patch max-one-of potential-destinations [utility-for myself]
    move-to best-patch
    end

   to do-accounting
  set wealth (wealth + profit)
   if random-float 1.0 < annual-risk
   [
    set wealth 0
    ]
     set current-utility utility-for self

     end

   to-report utility-for [a-turtle]

   let turtles-wealth [wealth] of a-turtle
   let utility turtles-wealth + (profit * decision-time-horizon)

    set utility utility * ((1 - annual-risk) ^ decision-time-horizon)

    report utility
    end
  end
```